# Cannot connect to Cassandra from Spark (Contact points contain multiple data centers)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to run my first spark job (a Scala job that accesses Cassandra) which is failing and showing the following error :

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {<ip>}:9042
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:164)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
...........
............
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contact points contain multiple data centers: 
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.init(LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala:47)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1099)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:271)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:157)
```

What are we doing wrong here?

I am using :

- Spark 1.5.2
- Apache Cassandra 2.1.10
- [spark-cassandra connector 1.3.1](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/1.3.1/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.3.1.jar) /1.5.0-M2 (tried both connectors)
- Scala version 2.10.4

Comment: How many machines and Data Centers are in your C* cluster. This should only happen if the contact points span multiple data centers and the driver is unable to determine what the "Local" datacenter is. This helps the connector avoid cross DC traffic.

Comment: Thanks RussS for your reply. We have a single data center and cassandra has 3 node cluster. Spark has a 4 node cluster(running with hadoop 1-master 3 datanodes). Both spark and cassandra running in different nodes

Comment: and have you set --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host to be one (or more) of the C* nodes?

Comment: Thanks Russ for the response, i think i got the problem, it must be a jar /classpath conflict. I have executed the sample code from spark-shell and loaded dependency jar one by one, the code has detected the cassandra cluster and nodes. I am planning to perform the same steps for the spark job which have problem. I will update you. Thanks

Comment: Hi Russ, the issue is specific to google cloud platform's dataproc. I am able to execute the same job in another standalone spark cluster.

Answer (score 2):

--> According to author there a work in progress to fix this. See comments below this answer.

I found this in the documentation, I hope it will help you :

```
override def init(cluster: Cluster, hosts: JCollection[Host]) {
    nodes = hosts.toSet
    // use explicitly set DC if available, otherwise see if all contact points have same DC
    // if so, use that DC; if not, throw an error
    dcToUse = localDC match { 
      case Some(local) => local
      case None => 
        val dcList = dcs(nodesInTheSameDC(contactPoints, hosts.toSet))
        if (dcList.size == 1) 
            dcList.head
        else 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Contact points contain multiple data centers: ${dcList.mkString(", ")}")
    }
    clusterMetadata = cluster.getMetadata
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fundhor, i had already checked this code. if you carefully see the exception message string, it is not printing any data which clearly shows the size is 0. The code is having problem to detect the DC. As i have mentioned above , it seems a classpath issue. I am trying to analyze the dependencies.

Comment: I got the same issue when running Spark job on AWS EMR Cassandra (multiple DC). @vimeghan: is there any update on this issue? tks.

Comment: Turn out that this is the issue of Spark-Cassandra-Connector itself, int class LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala (https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/cql/LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala). There's a pull request to fix this issue (link: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/pull/1140), but this pull did not merged yet. Hopefully this issue will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while trying to connect two Cassandra data center using Apache Spark 2.x.x.

```
public class  SparkCassandraTest {  
  private static final String CASSANDRA_ENDPOINTS = "DC1_node1,DC1_node2,DC1_node3,DC2_node1,DC2_node2,DC2_node3";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME);
        sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", CASSANDRA_ENDPOINTS);
        sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", CASSANDRA_USERNAME);
        sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", CASSANDRA_PASSWORD);
        sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();

        //.....................
        //.....................
        //.....................
       }
}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Contact points contain multiple data centers: DC2-XXXXX2, DC1-XXXXX1

I resolve this issue by connecting any one Cassandra data center (**DC1_node1**,**DC1_node2**,**DC1_node3**) or (**DC2_node1**,**DC2_node2**,**DC2_node3**).

Comment: Saho - did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm also facing the exact same issue and it works when I added only one datacenter.

Comment: I can able to connect only one Cassandra data center i.e (DC1_node1,DC1_node2,DC1_node3).

Comment: Spark is not allowing to connect multiple Cassandra data center.

Comment: Is that a limitation of Spark? For me this seems like a big issue.